# Sqlite database insert returns always -1 on some devices

Tags: database, insert, android-sqlite, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I try to insert an entry in sqlite db, but this does not work on some devices!
The insertion works with the device **Huawei Nexus 6P (Android 6.0, API23)** very well, but not with the device **Samsung SM-G930F (Android 6.0.1, API23)**.

Can you please help me! The return code is always "res = -1".
Here is my code for inserting a new registration:

public boolean insertRegistration(Registration registration) {

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("phoneNumber", registration.getPhoneNumber());
    cv.put("serverPassword", registration.getServerPassword());
    cv.put("chatPassword", registration.getChatPassword());
    cv.put("username", registration.getUsername());
    cv.put("fileURL", registration.getFileURL());

    long res = 0;
    try
    {
        res = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, cv);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        // Sep 12, 2013 6:50:17 AM
        Log.e("Exception", "SQLException" + String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(res == -1)
        throw new RuntimeException("New registration can not be inserted into local db");
    db.close();
    return res >= 0;
}
```

The debugger will also not come to the catch! No warning or errors will be returned!

And the db looks like this:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
>     db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_USER);
> }
> ```

Create user db string:

> private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_USER = "create table "
>               + TABLE_USER + "("
>               + "id integer primary key autoincrement, "
>               + "phoneNumber text not null, "
>               + "serverPassword text not null, "
>               + "chatPassword text not null, "
>               + "fileURL text not null, "
>               + "username text not null"
>               + ");";

I always get the return code "-1", if I debug this line "res = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, cv);" on the device "Samsung SM-G930F".

Thank you in Advance!